# Is possible in gremlin to count something inside a choose and then go back to a previous step?

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, tinkerpop3, gremlin-server

Is possible in gremlin to count something inside choose() and then go back to a previous step in the traversal?:

```
g.V()
.hasLabel("user1")
.as("firstStep")
.V()
.as("secondStep")
.fold()
.choose(
    count(local).is(gt(1)),
    select('firstStep'),
    select('secondStep')
)
```

The select('firstStep') line is executed but nothing is returned because at that point everything stored by .as("firstStep") was removed by fold()

Of course I can always solve this kind of problem at the expense of performance, duplicating the cost by searching 2 times:

```
g.V()
.hasLabel("user1")
.choose(
    V().fold().count(local).is(lt(2)),
    V().fold()
)
```

I'm looking for a better solution than this.

This is like if I go to a store and pay something, because I have to count the change I forget how to go back to my hose, the gremlins of the movie are more intelligent than that. I hope there is a solution that I ignore.

**EDIT:**
There is an answer recommending to replace as() by store() but that is not a general solution, doesn't work in most situations becase these are very different tools, for example this query has the same problem and replacing as() by store() gives a different result:

```
g.V()
.hasLabel('user')
.project("user")
.by(
    as("singleUser")
    .V()
    .fold()
    .choose(
        count(local).is(gt(1)),
        select('singleUser'),
        unfold()
    )
)
```

Answer (score -1):

In this pattern you can use `store` step, that way the "firstStep" will be saved after the `fold`.

```
g.V().hasLabel('user1').store('firstStep').
  V().
  fold().choose(
    count(local).is(gt(1)),
    select('firstStep').unfold(),
    select('secondStep')
  )
```

example: https://gremlify.com/mg7noyf1cdq

Comment: I don't think this answer is complete or useful, because store() is a very different tool, in almost all situations is not something meant to replace as(), because as() called 2 times with the same string the second time overwrites the first but store() adds the second time to a list, so it behaves different for example inside a project().by() see this 2 queries are the same except one uses as() and the other store(), the output is different: 1. https://gremlify.com/cmv4m0kd5v9 2. https://gremlify.com/bo94m3m3tcf/1 By the way, the store step is undocumente. I'll edit my post to include this